# HTML form calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This will be a silly question, just trying to figure my way around Javascript functions interacting with HTML forms and can't get it to work.

Extremely simple, put it in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAHZ2/30/)

```
$('#test').submit(function(){
    var battery = $('#battery').value();
    $('#output').text(battery);
});

<form id="test" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="battery">Cell Count</label><br />
        <input type="number" size="3" name="battery" id="battery" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="submit()" />
    </fieldset>
</form>

<div id="output">

</div>​​​​
```

​Always returns an error and I can't figure out why.  Have played around with  and other things, can't get it to work always error.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery you probably want to handle the click on your JS code and not inline in your HTML...

Comment: @elclanrs - Not only that, but a submit button will submit the form without any javascript all by itself.

Comment: Right.  I've been searching Stack Overflow all morning and this is why I changed val() to value(), however it still returns error.  I'm using the FF error console, but JSFiddle is just much easier for trial and error on something like this.  Once I get the function to at least start I'll start in the browser.  Thanks all.

Comment: Ok, well I've hosted it at bungle.ca/test.htm, gotten as far as an error on line 14 syntax error: illegal character.

Answer (score 4):

The error is probably that `.value()` isn't a function. You want `.val()`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's function for returning the value of an `input` element is `val()`, not `value()`. Your code should be:

```
$('#test').submit(function(){
    var battery = $('#battery').val();
    $('#output').text(battery);
});

<form id="test" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="battery">Cell Count</label><br />
        <input type="number" size="3" name="battery" id="battery" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="submit()" />
    </fieldset>
</form>

<div id="output">

</div>​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use proper developer tools (for example Firebug in Firefox) then you could easily figure out the problem here as in the console it would have shown you something like :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'value'
```

Which means that there is no `value` method and `val()` is what should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve values from inputs using jQuery you need to use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

**Change:**

```
var battery = $('#battery').value();
```

**to:**

```
var battery = $('#battery').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is correct, but I think your javascript code looks like php, and there's nothing in the `action=""` field in the quotes.  Also, I think that value should be val.

Answer (score 0):

The correct function is val() no value() in jquery.

By using the method .submit keep in the **"return false"** to not run the **"action"** of the **"form"** that you have not considered.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
        $('#test').submit(function(){
            var battery = $('#battery').val();
            $('#output').text(battery);
            return false;
        });        
    })

</script>
```

If you are using jQuery, you do not need the onclick="submit()" argument in the input object

```
<form id="test" action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="battery">Cell Count</label><br />
        <input type="number" size="3" name="battery" id="battery" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>​​​​
```

regards